# Bloqueio na porta 80 do apache

Tags: php, apache

Está sendo desenvolvido dentro da empresa uma aplicação para um controle, porém quando tento utilizar o apache em outras máquinas para que tenha acesso retorna um bloqueio

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /backup on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at 192.168.123.22 Port 80

Obs: Se colocar na 8080 ele reconhece normalmente, porém precisa ser a 80, estamos utilizando a ultima versão do apache.

Comment: Fecha o Skype...

Comment: @Gumball , se existir outra aplicação nesta porta ele não irá funcionar em nenhuma máquina ?

Comment: Você está usando é Wamp né?

Comment: @Gumball se o skype dele estiver na porta 80(padrão), não é necessário fechar, apenas definir uma porta diferente manualmente nas configurações do skype. :)

Comment: @Florida eu sei... mas era pra ele deduzir isso.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta *Forbidden* significa que você está acessando sim o Apache, mas a página não é autorizada, quero dizer isto não é um problema com a porta, é apenas um problema de permissões.

### WampServer

Provavelmente está usando [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), se for este o caso basta clicar na opção <kbd>Colocar online</kbd> (ou <kbd>Put online</kbd> se estiver em inglês) assim:

[image: wamp]

### Outros que não sejam WampServer

**Se estiver** usando outro tipo de servidor que usa Apache você deve editar o httpd.conf

Ele deve estar algo como (use o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> para procurar algo semelhante):

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/www">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

Neste caso bloqueia a todos e libera apenas os 3 últimos, então basta adicionar o que vai liberar, no caso o ip é `192.168.123.22` (se for fixo), então seria algo como:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
     Allow from 192.168.123.22 #Ip da sua maquina
</Directory>
```

E então reiniciei o Apache, reinicie o computador (as vezes só basta fazer <kbd>logoff</kbd> no Windows)

Ou remova tudo (faça um backup do `httpd.conf` primeiro, antes de editar qualquer coisa)

E então reiniciei o Apache.

Você disse que só ocorre com porta 80, isso é porque as configurações pode estar no `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

O `Require local` pode ser o motivo do bloqueio também (lembre-se antes de remover qualquer coisa faça um backup).

**Documentação:** https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Answer (score 1):

Abra o command prompt em modo administrativo e execute:

```
netstat -np TCP | find ":80"
```

Os IPs a esquerda é o seu IP local. O comando acima retornará dezenas ou centenas de resultados se estiver navegando ou com algo conectado a internet.

Um jeito rápido de filtrar e obter o que interessa é colocar o seu IP no comando

Exemplo, se o seu IP é 192.168.1.10

```
netstat -abnop TCP | find "192.168.1.10:80"
```

Isso retornará vazio se não houver nada.

Caso tenha algo, retornará:

```
TCP    192.xx    192.xx    ESTABLISHED    4444
```

O último número é o PID do processo em questão.

Para descobrir o nome do processo:

```
tasklist /fi "pid eq 4444"
```

Retorna:

```
Image Name      PID      Session Name    Session#     Mem Usage
processo.exe    4444     nome_sessao     2            10k
```

Assim você obtém o nome do programa que está ocupando a porta que deseja, no caso a porta 80.

Dois programas não podem ocupar a mesma porta.

Caso queira o Apache nessa porta que está em uso, deve interromper o outro programa ou mudá-lo para outra porta.

Obs: A sua questão ainda parece confusa porque a mensagem de erro para quando a porta está em uso é diferente da mensagem que está na pergunta.

A mensagem é normalmente relacionada com permissão de leitura e escrita de um determinado local físico.