# Wamp Server Forbidden error

Tags: apache, wamp

Estou tentando colocar um site online (um site basico só para testes), mas quando entro pelo meu ip seguido da porta 8080, já que a porta 80 costuma dar problema, eu recebo a a mensagem "Forbidden, you don't have permission to access / on this server" mesmo acessando pelo celular conectado a mesma rede. No entanto no meu pc funciona. Já configurei o httpd.conf. Uso o apache 5.6.25.

Comment: Olá Toniotti, esta resposta deve lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162048/3635